Powerpoint VBA Slide Rearranged Event
I'm trying to write a VBA macro for PowerPoint that updates a textbox based on the current section a slide is in. It was fairly straight forward to implement code that runs on the PresentationNewSlide event, however, I also want the code to run if the slide order is changed. The closest event I can find is SlideSelectionChanged, but that doesn't seem like the right fit.
Does anyone know of a way to run a macro when slides are re-ordered? Ideally, I only want to run it on the slides that have been moved, rather than all of them.

I may be wrong but my approach would be : 1. Have a public array at the open of the ppt saving the slide order (now how do you define this would be tricky, I can't recall that they work as excel where sheet# as object is static vs order in WB) 2: have a button at slide 1 to execute your macro (or have a toolbar for the ppt) then save another array 3. Have a sub that compares both arrays, exec for the ones that changed order and overwrite the first array when the WB opened with the second one.

As far as implementing it, you could have a routine that checks each slide for a tag whose value = the slide's .SlideIndex, update the textbox if there's a mismatch, then apply new values to the tag on each slide, making them equal to the slide's .SlideIndex. You could perhaps trigger this by trapping the SelectionChange event and in the event handler, testing to see if the current selection type is Slide(s).  The macro would trigger more often than it needs to but would run so quickly that it wouldn't matter, I expect.
